# accessing custom python type properties by name

Tags: python

in the code below i'm defining a type then using the properties as keys of a dictionary:

```
ProdType= namedtuple('ProdType', 'Cmdty Eqty Fixed')

prod_map = {ProdType.Cmdty: 'Commodities',
            ProdType.Eqty: 'Equities',
            ProdType.Fixed: 'Fixed Income'}
```

I know i can access the value in dictionary prod_map code like this:

```
descr = prod_map[ProdType.Cmdty],
```

but my question is, is it possible to access this map by a string value? such as:

```
  descr = prod_map['Cmdty']
```

I ask because some clients (for example a .net client) will be accessing this through a webservice and will only be able to pass a string value.

Thanks

Comment: What is `DB`?  Your example doesn't use `ProdType` at all.

Comment: you should try it and see what happens

Comment: sorry, i tried to  make the example simple and had some typos. i corrected the example.  @krock - i did, that's why i'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a namedtuple as an enumerated type.  This is not how namedtuples work.  Generate the namedtuple again with `verbose=True` to see what it creates:

```
>>> ProdType= namedtuple('ProdType', 'Cmdty Eqty Fixed', verbose=True)
class ProdType(tuple):
    ...
    def __new__(_cls, Cmdty, Eqty, Fixed):
        'Create new instance of ProdType(Cmdty, Eqty, Fixed)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (Cmdty, Eqty, Fixed))
    ...
    Cmdty = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')
    Eqty = _property(_itemgetter(1), doc='Alias for field number 1')
    Fixed = _property(_itemgetter(2), doc='Alias for field number 2')
```

The above shows that we just made a tuple class with property aliases for the 3 attributes we expect in each instance.  So really, you don't need a dictionary at all, you could just use instances of `ProdType` like this:

```
>>> pt = ProdType('Commodities', 'Equity', 'Fixed Income')
>>> pt.Cmdty
'Commodities'
>>> pt.Eqty
'Equity'
```

You should simply access the attributes of the namedtuple using the namedtuple properties (as above) but if you *really* need to access the namedtuple via strings you can use `__getattribute__` like this:

```
>>> pt.__getattribute__('Fixed')
'Fixed Income'
```

Comment: Yes re: enumerated types.  What it the equivalent way of doing this in python?   For now, looks like i am able to do something like this as a work around:  key = getattr(ProdType, key) if isinstance(key, basestring) else key

Comment: [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) has added enumerated types, but as far as my understanding of what you want to do I think creating an instance of the namedtuple (as in the second code block above) should suit your needs.